# ASM class reader failed to parse - due to class file version that isnt supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am new to spring and trying to learn Spring MVC, jdk-17, tomcat-9.0.74, spring-5.0.38

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [FrontController] threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Users\dhine\OneDrive\Documents\Eclipse

org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\Users\dhine\OneDrive\Documents\Eclipse Workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\Spring MVC\WEB-INF\classes\controllers\First.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 62
org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:60)

```
org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49)
org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:123)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:429)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:315)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:276)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:90)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1391)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1371)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:179)
```

I have tried downgrading jdk to 8, 17 from 18. But still no use.

Comment: You have a version of ASM on the classpath which does not support Java 18 (class version 62 means Java 18). Spring 5.0 is relatively "old", and it is likely it simply doesn't support such a new Java version, you may want to consider upgrading to Spring 5.3.

Comment: For Java 18 support, you need at least ASM version 9.2, but upgrading to that version will not necessarily make Spring 5.0 work on Java 18. As an aside, Java 18 went out of support a year ago. I'd suggest sticking to an LTS version like Java 17.